# String не распознает кириллицу

Tags: c#, кодировка, кириллица, строки

Есть такая проблема:

```
string str = (textBox22.Text);       
//В текстбоксе внесен текст "\u043f\u0442\u043e\u043b\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0439"(без кавычек)

string str2 = "\u043f\u0442\u043e\u043b\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0439";

Label1.text = str2;  // Выводит "птоломей"

Label1.text = str;  // выводит "\u043f\u0442\u043e\u043b\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0439"
```

ПОлучается что при подаче текста через ТекстБокс программа видит текст как он есть.
Вопрос: как форматнуть текст в кириллицу?

Comment: Да так и есть и в отладке 
str = '\\u043f\\u0442\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u043c\\u0435\\u0439'

Я искал настройки текстбокса и пробовал "дословные литералы", но ничего не получается у меня, вот и прошу помощи, может кто знает уже как такое провернуть.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string

Answer (score 1):

Текстбокс умный, понимает когда ему хотят подсунуть слеш и экранирует его. Т.е. str1 внутри - "`\\\u043f\\\u0442\\\u043e\\\u043b\\\u043e\\\u043c\\\u0435\\\u0439`"

Преобразовать его в человеческий вид можно например так:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape("\u043f\u0442\u043e\u043b\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0439");
```